# Change ReSharper Exception Intellisense

Tags: exception, resharper

I currently am using the ReSharper tool (Version 6 Trial) and I'm having some problems with the exceptions that it allows me to throw in its intellisense. For instance, I want to be able to throw an ArgrumentOutOfRangeException yet the only two that appear in the intellisense are a custom exception and the default System.Exception.

What setting do I use in order to get the entire list of exceptions? Is this possible? I know that I can default back to Visual Studio's intellisense but that is not really what I'm after.

**Edit:** I have uninstalled using Revo Uninstaller. I've reinstalled the trial version. Still nothing. Only the two exceptions that I mentioned earlier. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - (free copy through my university).

Comment: I have checked in Visual Studio 2008 with ReSharper 6.0. Not facing the problem. Intellisense shows all the available exceptions when I type `throw new`. Have you tried reinstalling ReSharper?

Comment: Do you think its possible that its only just a trial that I'm not quite getting all the features? I do have `using System;`. This was literally just installed a couple hours ago. I didn't change any settings. I can try re-installing though.

Comment: ReSharper will insert the using statement in case there isn't one for the corresponding exception, when the exception is added through intellisense. The trial version is not limited by features, it only limits the number of days you can use the software.

Comment: Try posting the question at [ReSharper community forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ReSharper trial is fully functional: you should be definitely getting all features.

Here's a [bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274940) that is very similar to your problem - please vote and watch if you like to.

I don't think we at JetBrains have a consistent repro case though - for me personally, it works ok. Might be your specific configuration where service packs or installed frameworks may matter.

As a workaround, try explicitly invoking ReSharper symbol completion (Ctrl+Space) or Import symbol completion (Ctrl+Alt+Space in IntelliJ keymap) to see if different Exception types show up.

UPDATE! The bug is fixed, the fix should be available in ReSharper 6.1 that is scheduled for release in October.